# CREAR CLASE CURSOR SQLITE3

Tags: python, sqlite3, cursor

> Cita en bloque

Hola, estoy haciendo una aplicación en Python que sirve para hacer CRUD con bases de datos con la librería sqlite3. El problema es que cuando creo el cursor en la función "CrearBaseDeDatos()" ya no es accesible en la función actualizaBaseDeDatos(), entonces decidí crear una clase cursor que fuera global en todo el código, el problema es que no sé como le puedo hacer para crear solo el cursor sin crear una conexión porque si no me da error. ¿ Alguien puede proponer una solución o darme otras alternativas por favor ?
Les dejo mi código:

> Cita en bloque

```
from tkinter import*
from tkinter import messagebox
import sqlite3


class cursor:





    conn=sqlite3.connect("N")
    conn.cursor()
    


#Función CREATE

def CrearBaseDeDatos():

    
    try:

        conectar=sqlite3.connect("Usuarios")
        
        cur=cursor()
        cur.conn.execute('''CREATE TABLE DATOSUSUARIOS(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT , NOMBRE_USUARIO VARCHAR(50), PASSWORD VARCHAR(20), APPELIDO VARCHAR(50), DIRECCION VARCHAR(50), COMENTARIOS VARCHAR(1000))''')
        
        messagebox.showinfo("Base de datos creada", "La base de datos se ha creado con exito")

        
    
    except ValueError:

        messagebox.showwarning("Error", "La base de datos ya existe")



def actualizaBaseDeDatos():

    
    
    curActualiza=cursor()
    curActualiza.conn.executemany('''INSERT INTO DATOSUSUARIOS VALUES (?,?,?,?)''', listaDeDatos)

    
#---------- Interfaz Grafica ----------

#Raiz

root=Tk()
root.title("Applicacion base de datos")
root.iconbitmap("imagen_BBDD.ico")

#Menu

barraMenu=Menu(root)
root.config(menu=barraMenu)

BaseMenu=Menu(barraMenu, tearoff=0)
BaseMenu.add_command(label="Conectar")
BaseMenu.add_command(label="Salir")


BorrarMenu=Menu(barraMenu, tearoff=0)
BorrarMenu.add_command(label="Borrar campos")

CRUDMenu=Menu(barraMenu,tearoff=0)
CRUDMenu.add_command(label="Crear", command=lambda:CrearBaseDeDatos())
CRUDMenu.add_command(label="Leer")
CRUDMenu.add_command(label="Actualizar")
CRUDMenu.add_command(label="Eliminar")

ayudaMenu=Menu(barraMenu)



barraMenu.add_cascade(label="BBDD", menu=BaseMenu)
barraMenu.add_cascade(label="Borrar", menu=BorrarMenu)
barraMenu.add_cascade(label="CRUD", menu=CRUDMenu)
barraMenu.add_cascade(label="Ayuda", menu=ayudaMenu)

#Labels

labelId=Label(text="id: ").grid(row=1, column=1, pady=10, padx=10)
labelNombre=Label(text="Nombre: ").grid(row=2, column=1, pady=10, padx=10)
labelApellido=Label(text="Apellido: ").grid(row=3, column=1, pady=10, padx=10)
labelDireccion=Label(text="Direccion: ").grid(row=4, column=1, pady=10, padx=10)
labelComentarios=Label(text="Comentarios: ").grid(row=5, column=1, pady=10, padx=10)

#Entrys

entryID=Entry(justify="center")
entryID.grid(row=1,column=2)
entryNombre=Entry(justify="center", fg="red")
entryNombre.grid(row=2,column=2)
entryApellido=Entry(justify="center")
entryApellido.grid(row=3,column=2)
entryDireccion=Entry(justify="center")
entryDireccion.grid(row=4,column=2)




#Texto comentarios 


textoComentarios=Text(root, width=16, height=5)
textoComentarios.grid(row=5, column=2)


ScrollBar=Scrollbar(root, command=textoComentarios.yview)
ScrollBar.grid(row=5, column=3, sticky="nsw")
textoComentarios.config(yscrollcommand=ScrollBar.set)

listaDeDatos=[entryNombre.get(),entryApellido.get(),entryDireccion.get(),textoComentarios.get('1.0',END)]
print(listaDeDatos)

#Botones de CRUD

BotonCreate=Button(root, text="Create", command=lambda:CrearBaseDeDatos())
BotonCreate.grid(row=6, column=1, pady=10, padx=10)

BotonRead=Button(root, text="Read")
BotonRead.grid(row=6, column=2, pady=10, padx=10)

BotonUpdate=Button(root, text="Update", command=lambda:actualizaBaseDeDatos())
BotonUpdate.grid(row=6, column=3, pady=10, padx=10)

BotonDelete=Button(root, text="Delete")
BotonDelete.grid(row=6, column=4, pady=10, padx=10)





root.mainloop()
```

Comment: La alternativa usual es pasar el cursor como parámetro a las funciones que lo necesiten. En tu caso,  `CrearBaseDeDatos` deberia retornar el cursor que ha creado, y `actualizaBaseDeDatos` tendría que recibirlo como parámetro. Hay que evitar el uso de variables globales, pues son fuente de errores y confusiones.